# How can I fetch Intercom users using Python API with a particular filter?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, api, intercom

How to fetch users from Intercom Python API using the tag last seen less than  2 days ago or else creating the segment in UI for the same will it be possible to fetch all users in Segment which I have created with filter 'last seen less than 2 days ago'?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by either tag or segment - while setting those two up may be quite different and that's a different conversation - querying by either of them is quite similar.

You can fetch segmented users/leads by querying the users resource with a `segment_id` parameter, indicating the `id` of the segment to query with.

To fetch tagged users/leads, you can use a `tag_id` parameter to indicate the `id` of the tag. For information on tagging users see the section ['Tag or Untag Users'](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference#tag-or-untag-users-companies-leads-contacts).

So, ultimately you would query against the users endpoint like this: `https://api.intercom.io/users?tag_id=3142` OR `https://api.intercom.io/users?segment_id=5926`

If you're using [python-intercom](https://github.com/intercom/python-intercom), then your query may look like this: `intercom.users.find(tag_id=3142)` OR `intercom.users.find(segment_id=5926)`

Note that you can not combine tag and segment parameters in the same request. This information can be found in the documentation [here](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference#list-by-tag-segment-company).

Hopefully this helps! Let me know if any follow up is needed~